# count likes in ManyToManyField - django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

in models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    liked_by = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='liked_by')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date']
```

in serializers.py:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializers()
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('body','date','user')
```

how to count likes of a single post? and also show which user liked the post.

Comment: If you are building a rest application with django try avoiding using m2m relationships since DRF doesn't really have support for it (it introduces alot of nested objects)

Comment: sir @SLDem, what i should use instead of ManyToMany relationship? i'm new in drf

Comment: try creating a seperate relationship table with 2 foreign keys to each member of the relationship and extract data from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializers()
    total_likes = serilaizers.SerializerMethodField()
    liked_by = UserSerializers(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('body','date','user', 'total_likes', 'liked_by')

    def get_total_likes(self, instance):
      return instance.liked_by.count()
```

Comment: I'm getting an error `ImportError: cannot import name 'UserSerializer'` where I tried importing the UserSerializer `from users.serializers import UserSerializer` but it is still showing error. My user model is in another APP.

Comment: Use appName.serializers import UserSerializer

Comment: `users` is my app name

Answer (score 0):

Your liked_by field is just referencing to User model, but not to User model and you have only who liked your post but likes quantity. So you can query certain post and count User quantity, but I suggest to have separate filed of likes count

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to change class Post manyToMany relation adding "through=".

   liked_by = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='liked_users', blank=True, related_name='liked_by')
2. Create manually model LikedUsers:

class LikedUsers(models.Model):
liked_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='likedusers', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='likedusers', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

3. Get access to likes (post.likedusers[0].liked_count, ... next users)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the total likes of a post using SerializerMethodField.

```
from rest_framework.fields import SerializerMethodField

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializers()
    total_likes = SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('body','date','user')

    def get_total_likes(self, instance):
        return instance.liked_by.all().count()
```